# repairing grub and efi

Tags: grub2

Today I tried to replace my Ubuntu install with Debian. I also have Kali installed. Before starting the installer, I thought it would be 'fun' to try

```
rm -rf /*
```

on my Ubuntu install. But I didn't unmount the `efi` partition and it got wiped out. It turns out the Debian installer has a bug and it failed to install Grub. I skipped the Grub installation and completed the rest of the steps. I `chroot`ed to Debian and installed Grub2. But the command

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

is acting weirdly. It says:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for sda.  Check your device.map.
```

First, I have a 64 bit system and second, sda1 partition is set with flags `boot` and `ESP`. Anybody knows what is the problem here, and what is the solution?

Solution:
For some reason `apt-get install grub`, installed grub-efi-ia32 along with it. Installing the package grub-efi-amd64 solved the problem.

Comment: When you chroot'd to the Debian install, did you make sure both `/proc` and  `/sys` were mounted inside the chroot?

Comment: Yep, proc sys and dev

Answer (score 2):

If your current version of Debian have `systemd-boot`, I would recommend using that instead. It is much easier to use. Just follow the guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot).

I wouldn't bother with Grub when it comes to UEFI. The new `systemd-boot` (`bootctl`) is much easier and incorporated in `systemd`. I gave up on `grub efi` a long time ago. Also just ask any questions if you want to try my method.

Comment: Please don't rely on external sites and describe the relevant content in your answer.

Comment: Really? That is a lot of work when I don't even know if he wants to use bootctl or can.

Comment: Yes, really. Why did you link to Arch's wiki?

Comment: Because debians wiki don't have one and also I like Arch's wiki. It is also the one I used to learn how to fix debians issues with UEFI.